# Bounded function on $m(E) = 0$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $f$ is a bounded function on a set $X$ of measure $0$, prove that $f$ is measurable and $\int_{X}\ f = 0$.

**My attempt:** I tried to show that the upper Lebesgue integral is equal to the lower Lebesgue integral. This is equivalent to show:

$\sup\left\{\int_{X} \phi \ | \ \phi \ \text{is simple function and}\  \phi\leq f\ \text{on X}  \right\} = \inf \left\{\int_{X} \phi \ | \ \phi \ \text{is simple function and}\  \phi\geq f\ \text{on X} \right\}$.

However, I couldn't see how to relate these sup and inf with $m(X) = 0$. Can someone please help me on this problem?

Comment: How are $E$ and $X$ related?

Comment: @ZachGershkoff: thanks for your help. I corrected it:) Please give this problem a try if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that a function $f$ is measurable, you show that all the pullbacks of the level sets are measurable sets. The pullbacks of levels sets are subsets of $X$, and $X$ has measure $0$, and so do all of its subsets.

To show that $\int_X f = 0$, rather than using sup or inf, I think it's easier to let $b$ be the bound on the absolute value of $f$, and then $|\int_X f| \leq |b m(X)|$.

Comment: Your 2nd hint is absolutely correct (I found out the same argument)!! Can you clarify on the first part (i.e, what do you mean by the "pullbacks of level sets"?) And from your hint, it seems to me we didn't have to prove $sup = inf$ to conclude $f$ measurable??

Comment: Regarding the second part, since $b$ is the bound, $-bm(X) \leq \sup \{ \phi \leq f \} \leq \inf \{ \phi \geq f \} \leq bm(X)$.

Regarding the first part, it's not super important what I meant by "pullbacks of level sets". Sorry if that was confusing. The point is that by the definition of measurable function, you want to look at the preimages of sets in the domain under $f$, and any such preimage must be a subset of $X$, so it will have measure $0$ and therefore be a measurable set.

Comment: Thanks for your further explaination. For the 2nd part, I think it's sufficient to show that $0\leq |\int_{E} f|\leq 0$. For the first part, good proof! I was so dumb not to realize the set $E_0 ={x\in E: f(x)>c}$ must have measure $0$:p